# Accessing the Postgres terminal history with dates

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to do some 'detective work': I can cycle through previous commands sent to PostgreSQL through the commandline (Ubuntu) for user `postgres` (up arrow); is there any way to list the history with a date/time next to each command?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the `readline` library for command line editing, and that doesn't store the time of the commands.

So no luck there.

Comment: its just a standard terminal and then logged in to psql. ICT changed the user password without informing me, then denied doing it, I only wanted to know so I can adjust the visitor stats. Probably not the place to rant but never under estimate a digital archaeologist with 10 years of server/database experience. I don't think they like me because I know when they say 'its not possible', it just means they can't do it. #rantend

Comment: I have been wrong before, but I'd be surprised if you find a way.